# How can i Send (Silent push Notification to a Unity Client Application)?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

i am currently using Firebase SDK to send push notifications for my Unity game and it's working perfectly.

now i am gonna change my plan and use silent notification and handle it from the unity side ,
is there an SDK other than (FCM) that enables Unity to Handle Silent push notifications ?

Comment: what are `Silent push notifications`?

Comment: Notifications from FCM are already silent ... it doesn't make any sound

Comment: a notification that contains custom data and has no sound

Comment: the question here is how to handle it in Background